# $emit event is not being heard in Vue components

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue application where a parent component needs to emit an event, it does this in a button:

```
<button @click.prevent="saveTradeClick" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

It triggers a method:

```
  saveTradeClick: function (event) {
    console.log("click");
    this.$emit('SAVE');
    console.log("after emit");
  },
```

and a child component should listen to this event to trigger a method.

```
    mounted() {
   this.$parent.$on('SAVE', this.submitTrade);
}
```

This is not working. I get the `console.log('click');` however, I get nothing out of the child component.

When I look in the Vue devtools I get an `$emit` event but that is all. Any ideas where I could go with this?

Comment: Did you make sure that the child is mounted by the time the parent emits the event?

Comment: This is much cleaner. Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue()

Answer (score 0):

I suggest controlling the state from the parent to have more control instead of your child component relying on your maybe-not-available parent.

### Example:

**Parent**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click.prevent="saveTradeClick" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <child :traded="traded"></child>
  <div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ traded: false }),
  methods: {
    saveTradeClick() {
      this.traded = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
  <div><div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['traded'],
  watch:{
    traded(val) {
      if (val) this.submitTrade();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[Vue unwritten rules](https://gambardella.info/2017/09/13/vue-js-communication-part-2-parent-child-components/)

- Parents are allowed to reference children, e.g. via props or refs
- Children do not have any reference to the parent
- Children do not change data that is passed via props.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea for If you would like a child component to listen for events from the parent is to create an `Event Bus`.

Now this feature does not come out of the box ready to use so you have to actually create a new instance of Vue and then export the `EventBus` feature like so.

eventbus.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

You would then import the `EventBus` into the components you would like to interact with.

parent component

```
<template>
  <div class="pleeease-click-me" @click="emitGlobalClickEvent()"></div>
</template>

<script>
// Import the EventBus we just created.
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';

export default {
  name: 'Parent',
  data() {
    return {
      clickCount: 0
    }
  },

  methods: {
    emitGlobalClickEvent() {
      this.clickCount++;
      // Send the event on a channel (i-got-clicked) with a payload (the click count.)
      EventBus.$emit('i-got-clicked', this.clickCount);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

So in your child component you can now listen for the event `i-got-clicked`

child component

```
<script>
// Import the EventBus we just created.
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';

export default {
  name: 'Child',

  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('i-got-clicked', clickCount => {
     console.log(`Oh, that's nice. It's gotten ${clickCount} clicks! :)`)
  });
}
</script>
```

and `clickCount` was passed from the parent so you can share data a long with listening for events.

And another solution depending on the size of your application is to look in to [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)